# Android: Live Video Streaming

Tags: android, ftp, live-streaming

I have an app that download a video from ftp then save on sd card in encrypted form , when user want to see that videos , then it decrpted and then showing but i have a problem with that is takes long dely on decrption. Is there any way to play a video like live streaming when it is in decrption process.

Comment: I dont know if it works while decrypting once file is 10% start the player supplying the in progress file name to it might work

Comment: it might work if you have a http-server running in your app. 1st send a streaming request from inside your app. 2nd the server then starts decrypting and provides the decrypted file for stream. 3rd should start after a little while.

Answer (score 0):

To implement your streaming scheme, you need two main components: a streaming server such as a local http instance and a javax.crypto.CipherInputStream. LocalSingleHttpServer is an example of that kind of implementation.